# How to allow any value to be entered in input in React-Select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I'm using react select to render a select component:

```
const options = [...]

<Select
 ...
 options={options}
/>
```

The problem is that I any value that I type that is not inside `options` won't get selected (when the select component is not focused the value will disappear).

Is there any way to make `<Select/>` more of a suggestions component that provides autocomplete for `options` but also allows any value to be entered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can use the `creatable` Component to achieve that:**

Example from [react-select](https://react-select.com/creatable)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import CreatableSelect from 'react-select/creatable';
import { colourOptions } from '../data';

export default class CreatableSingle extends Component<*, State> {
  handleChange = (newValue: any, actionMeta: any) => {
    console.group('Value Changed');
    console.log(newValue);
    console.log(`action: ${actionMeta.action}`);
    console.groupEnd();
  };
  handleInputChange = (inputValue: any, actionMeta: any) => {
    console.group('Input Changed');
    console.log(inputValue);
    console.log(`action: ${actionMeta.action}`);
    console.groupEnd();
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <CreatableSelect
        isClearable
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        onInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
        options={colourOptions}
      />
    );
  }
}
```